# serialization DataContract and NULL datamember

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, null

I am having a problem serializing null value. actually I don't want to include it at all.

```
[DataContract]
public class SearchItem{
   public SearchCriteria()
    {
        IsActive = true;
        IsFiltered = true;
    }

    [DataMember(Order=01)]
    public bool? IsActive { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order=02)]
    public bool IsPriceFiltered { get; set; }

}
```

and when I want to instanciate like

```
 new SearchCriteria(){
 IsActive = null, 
}
```

it still does serialize `IsActive` property.

any suggestions how to overcome this problem?

solutions like create as  `enum` or instantiate with other `constructor` NOT a options for me.

Comment: What is your serializer?

Comment: Put [DataIgrore] attribute on the property you don't want to serialize

Comment: It is conditional. OP wants to ignore if property is null! @GeorgeFindulov

Comment: serializer is protobuff i think

Answer (score 0):

You can use [EmitDefaultValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute.EmitDefaultValue);k(SolutionItemsProject);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true).

```
[DataMember(Order=01, EmitDefaultValue=false)]
public bool? IsActive { get; set; }
```

Comment: I dont think this works as per my needs, due to the fact it creates `xsi:nil="true"` attribute. I want to have it blank.